# How to show logged in users in a Brocade ICX6430 switch

Tags: brocade

What is the command to list the users currently logged into a Brocade ICX6430 switch?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `show telnet` will list all the users currently logged into the switch, both via telnet and ssh.